# Python list integrateUpper/Lowercase check?

Tags: python, list, uppercase, lowercase

I currently use following code to select rows from a dataframe:

```
list = ['3d block','3D Block','3D block','3d Block','cafe','Cafe']
data[data['description'].str.contains('|'.join(list))]
```

As you can see, I currently implement different queries for upper/lowercase, as I realized that '3d print' didn't really match all the items in question.

Can the code above be improved or shortened, so that the list includes all possible variations of upper/lowercase characters, both for one and two words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a *case InSeNsitIvE* selection  by passing the `case` parameter as `False`:

```
lst = ['3D Block', 'cafe']
data[data['description'].str.contains('|'.join(lst), case=False)]
```

And remember to not use `list` as a name as this will shadow the builtin `list` function, and make it unusable later in your code.

---

Reference:

[pandas.Series.str.contains](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: Nice. Forgot about that one! small nit, just mention not using `list` as a *list* name

Comment: Yes, added that too

Answer (score 2):

You can simply convert them all to lower using the `string.lower()` function

Make your list contain only lower case characters. But you can do a safe check for that too

```
my_list=['3d block', 'cafe']

# As karthik suggested, just to be safe, convert your list to lowercase
for i in range(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i]=ele.lower()

my_query='3D bLoCk'
if my_query.lower() in my_list:
    print('yes')
```

prints `yes`

Comment: You would have to convert the original list to lower too. Also, `list` is a bad variable name